# d3 v5 interpolate color on treemap

Tags: d3.js, colors, treemap

I'm working on building a treemap in d3 v5 based on this example: https://www.d3indepth.com/layouts/

I can use the `score` data point for the color scale on the lowest level children, but I'd like the parents of the boxes above to have an average of the children below.

A sample of my data is here:

```
{
 "name": "Unit",
 "children": [
  {
    "name": "SBU",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "App",
        "value": 3000,
        "score": 0.5
      },
      {
        "name": "App",
        "value": 3500,
        "score": 0.1
      },
      {
        "name": "App",
        "value": 2000,
        "score": 0.9
      }
    ]
  }
```

Code below:

```
d3.json("health.json").then(function(data) {
  console.log(data)

var treemapLayout = d3.treemap()
  .size([1700, 1500])
  .paddingOuter(16);

var rootNode = d3.hierarchy(data)

// Determine the size and placement of the boxes
rootNode
  .sum(function(d) { return d.value; })
  .sort(function(a,b) { return b.value - a.value; });

treemapLayout(rootNode);

var nodes = d3.select('svg g')
  .selectAll('g')
  .data(rootNode.descendants())
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', function(d) {return 'translate(' + [d.x0, d.y0] + ')'})

nodes
  .append('rect')
  .attr('width', function(d) { return d.x1 - d.x0; })
  .attr('height', function(d) { return d.y1 - d.y0; })
  .attr('style', function(d) {
      return ('fill:' + d3.interpolateRdYlGn(d.data.health))
  })

nodes
  .append('text')
  .attr('dx', 4)
  .attr('dy', 14)
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.data.name;
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do it is to preprocess the data to include the parent nodes' average child score, and the color for each node:

1. Calculate the average child score for each of the parent nodes, and add the result to your data-structure.

   ```
   {
     "name": "SBU",
     "avgScore": 0.5,
     "children: [
   ```
2. Use a sequential scale to map these average results to a particular color in e.g. d3.interpolateRdYlGn, and add the result to the data:

   ```
   const colorScale = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateRdYlGn)
     .domain([0, 1]); // depending on your data

   const nodeColor = colorScale(data.parent.avgScore);

   {
     "name": "SBU",
     "avgScore": 0.5,
     "nodeColor": nodeColor
   }
   ```
3. You could then assign specific colors to the data for the root and child nodes:

   ```
   const childNodeColor = rgb(100, 200, 100);
   {
     // Child node
     ...,
     nodeColor: childNodeColor
   }
   ```
4. Then simply render the color for each node in your tree using:

   ```
   ...
   .attr('style', function(d) {
     return colorScale(d.nodeColor);
   });
   ```

Comment: I think you're right - processing it on the back end prior to it landing with D3 is the way to go...